# SOLR connection issue while installing Sitecore 9.1.1

Tags: solr, sitecore-install-framework

While installing sitecore 9.1.1, getting solr connection issue even Solr is Connecting porperly.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the screenshot, it seems like your solr is listening on port number **8983**, While your sitecore instance is hitting on port number **8984**.

Answer (score 0):

Because in Sitecore installation process, Stopping Solr service for adding all cores. While starting solr service, it take longer time for connection cause the issue.

For that, we can add some extra delay time after SOLR service start. we can do it by change "Post Delay" Value in "xconnect-solr.json" and "sitecore-solr.json" at Solr Start display as below.

[image]

Comment: This answer that you have is a valid answer for a different problem. However, it is not the answer for this problem. The script is trying to connect to port 8984 and you are displaying a solar version with a port number 8983.